# Start the unity panel through the command line?

Tags: unity, gnome, command-line, gnome-panel

In previous versions of Ubuntu I could start the panel by typing `gnome-panel` into a terminal. This would cause the top and bottom panels to appear, helpful, for example, if I was in a different desktop environment at the moment (e.g., Openbox) and wanted to open the panel. Is there an equivalent command to start the unity panel from the command line? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `unity` in terminal and it should start unity.